# php artisan migrate error PDOEXception access denied laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

[image]

im new to laravel. im trying to do php artisan migrate but there is a displayed error. any ideas or clues, suggestions? any help would greatly appreciated.

my mysql has no password, username is root and host is localhost and also i already update the database.php with my mysql config in the config folder of laravel.

Comment: Sounds like you're pulling in the credentials from the .env file. Check that and change it.

Comment: solved. thank you. I'm having a hard time finding the .env file because it changed into a maya app icon.

Comment: @AndrewCaulfield Yes. and when i run the php artisan make:migration create_projects_and_tasks_tables --create="projects" i got this error [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
 Class 'dodong\Providers\AppServiceProvider' not found .. any ideas of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your .env file and reconfigure settings that suits your needs.